# Wgat can be used in instead of localStorage?

Tags: local-storage, nuxt.js

In vuejs2/vuex3 app I used localStorage for keeping data and also it was used to keep user's data when browser was refreshed, like:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {// store data
        status: '',
        token: localStorage.getItem('token') || '',
    ...

    getters: {

        token(state) {
            if (state.token.length > 0) {
                return state.token;
            }
            let token = localStorage.getItem('token')
            if (token != null && typeof token === 'string') {
                if (token.length > 0) {
                    return token;
                }
            }
            return [];
        }, // token(state) {
    ...
```

But starting work with nuxt looks like localStorage can not be used.
What can it be replaced with ?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to use the SSR option of Nuxt? If not, you can choose the SPA mode which is not different than a Vue project (while keeping the folder structure and other benefits of Nuxt).

Comment: Yes,  I need to use the SSR option. What can be used in this case ?

Comment: In that case, using cookies would probably be better or an external package like this: https://github.com/bazzite/vue-warehouse